# LaTeX system-wide glossary database as custom package

Tags: glossaries, package-writing, package-options

I'm trying to make a system-wide glossary database (with acronyms and definitions) as a package.

My file is: `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/myglossary.sty`

One needs to run:

```
sudo texhash
```

so that TeXLive sees the file.

Of course, I don't need all the definitions every time. So I split the definitions by domain.

File: `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/myglossary.sty`

```
% myglossary.sty
% acronyms and definitions

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myglossary}

\RequirePackage{glossaries}

\DeclareOption{computer}{\option@computer} %% Execute \option@computer if option computer

\newcommand\option@computer{%
  \newacronym{w3c}{W3C}{World Wide Web Consortium}

  \newglossaryentry{css}{%
    name={CSS},%
    description={Style sheet language used for describing the presentation semantics (the look and formatting) of a document written in a markup language.},%
    plural={CSS}}
}

\ProcessOptions

\endinput
```

File: `~/Desktop/test/document.tex`:

```
% document.tex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[computer]{myglossary}% note the option "computer"

\begin{document}

  \gls{w3c}
  \gls{css}

\end{document}
```

Compiled using:

```
pdflatex document.tex
```

The error is:

```
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `w3c' has already been defined.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just from personal interest: in my understanding the glossaries mechanism is somewhat similar to the bibtex logic. This means I can add as many entries a I like and makeindex/xindy take care that only the entries that are used in the document get to the glossary. Therefore I don't see any needs to segment the myglossary package into domains. The only thing where I could imagine this to be useful is when you want to change the explanations depending on the audience you write for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably would rather set the option as a boolean switch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myglossary.sty}
% myglossary.sty
% acronyms and definitions

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myglossary}

\RequirePackage{glossaries}

\newif\if@myglossary@computer

\DeclareOption{computer}{\@myglossary@computertrue} %
\ProcessOptions

\if@myglossary@computer
\newacronym{w3c}{W3C}{World Wide Web Consortium}

\newglossaryentry{css}{%
    name={CSS},%
    description={Style sheet language used for describing the presentation semantics (the look and formatting) of a document written in a markup language.},%
    plural={CSS}}
\fi

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[computer]{myglossary}% note the option "computer"
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

  \gls{w3c}
  \gls{css}

\end{document}
```

[image]